# In Twitter Bootstrap 3 button (checkbox) remains gray after it is unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I use Twitter Bootstrap 3 and have this code:

```
<div class="btn-group" id="day-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="fruits" id="apple" value="1" type="checkbox" />Apple
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input name="fruits" id="orange" value="2" type="checkbox" />Orange
    </label>
</div>
```

I click on the "Apple" and that button (checkbox) is gray. It is checked now.

Then I click on the "Apple" again. It is unchecked now. But it is still gray. Only if I click somewhere else it will be white, so I can see, that checkbox is unchecked.

I want to see white button (checkbox) right after it is unchecked, without having to click somewhere else. How could I achieve that? jQuery, css or other ways?

Answer (score 0):

This might have something to do with that your HTML is incorrect. If you look at the documentation of Bootstrap on [forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms), you'll see they use the following for inputs.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
</div>
```

So, modify your following

```
<label class="btn btn-default">
    <input name="fruits" id="orange" value="2" type="checkbox" />Orange
</label>
```

To this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="orange">Orange</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="orange" placeholder="Orange">
</div>
```

[Bootstrap on form controls](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls) -> Below an example of Bootstrap using a checkbox in both disabled and non-disabled form

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    Option one is this and that&mdash;be sure to include why it's great
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox disabled">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="" disabled>
    Option two is disabled
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I think my html is correct because of [this example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio). And I can't modify my html your way because I want lable to be on the button, not the side.

Comment: Ah, missed that one. My bad. However, have you tried to use `btn-primary` instead of `btn-default`? In the example you send that's what they use, so could be that the styling defaults correctly with `btn-primary`. `btn-default seems to be more used with Modals.

Comment: I've tried to use btn-primary with no luck. Actually, I think that the only difference between btn-default and btn-primary is a color.